# TypeScript addEventListener

Tags: typescript

I have a basic TS class in which I am trying to binding a event listener:

```
class MyBasicClass {

    private items = [];

    initialize(grid) {

        addEventListener(EVENT_VALUE_CHANGED, function (e: Event) {
            //this.items.push(e.detail);
            console.log('ADD UNDO');
        });
    }
}
```

I need to add items to the class member (which cannot be static) but do not understand how to access the 'this' of the class from within the context of event listener. Something that has always evaded me.

Do I have to do `var obj = this` and access the global inside the event handler?

Comment: You can just use `(e: Event) => { .. }`.

Comment: Ahh seems to work :) I have seen this syntax but not really worked with it a lot. What difference does it make, or was it introduced to solve this problem?

Comment: There are several reasons, check for example https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/ Google is your friend :-)

Comment: 100% I wasn't even sure what to Google, thank you!